# Filterering a list based on a multiselect array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a filter component where I filter a list with people based on multiple input values. The inputs based on strings filter with no problem, but when I select more than 1 item on the multi select, nothing is shown, I assume because `person.role` does not contain both values in the array.

```
<!-- rest of form -->
<v-select
  outlined
  multiple
  v-model="filter.roleFilter"
  :items="['Designer', 'Developer']"
/>
<!-- rest of form -->
```

The filter function

```
 computed: {
   filteredPeople() {
      const searchVal = this.search;
      const type = this.filter.accountypeFilter;
      const role = this.filter.roleFilter; 
      const start = this.filter.dateStartFilter;
      const end = this.filter.dateEndFilter;

      if (type === '' && role === '' && start === '' && end === '' && searchVal === '') {
        return this.people; // return everything if no filters are selected
      }
      // return the array after passing it through the filter function
      return this.people.filter((person) => (type === '' || person.accountType === type)
        && (role === '' || person.role.includes(role)) // <--- the problem is with this line
        && (start === '' || person.dateStart === start)
        && (end === '' || person.dateEnd === end)
        && (searchVal === '' || person.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())));
    },
  }
```

Is there something like `role.every(person.role.includes(role))` so I can make this work?

Comment: What does `role` returns? `string` or `array`?

Comment: You can use `role.every(r => person.role.includes(r))` which will return `true` if `person` has `all roles` which are `selected` from `multiselect`. Or you can use `some` instead of `every` if you want to show person who has `any one or more roles` `selected` from `multiselect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below, this will work only if a person has single role

```
computed: {
   filteredPeople() {
      const searchVal = this.search;
      const type = this.filter.accountypeFilter;

      // if the this.filter.roleFilter is array of stings keep this as it is
      const role = this.filter.roleFilter; 

      // else if it is of array objects somethings like [{value: "123", test: "test"}] do the below
      // const role = this.filter.roleFilter.map(x => x.value); 
      const start = this.filter.dateStartFilter;
      const end = this.filter.dateEndFilter;

      if (type === '' && role === '' && start === '' && end === '' && searchVal === '') {
        return this.people; // return everything if no filters are selected
      }
      // return the array after passing it through the filter function
      return this.people.filter((person) => (type === '' || person.accountType === type)
        && (role.length === 0 || role.includes(person.role)) // <--- the problem is with this line
        && (start === '' || person.dateStart === start)
        && (end === '' || person.dateEnd === end)
        && (searchVal === '' || person.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())));
    },
  }
```

Comment: That did the trick! Why does it work the other way around and not my way?

Comment: person.role was a string and you were searching in the array in a string, which is not correct. What did work `const role = this.filter.roleFilter;` or `const role = this.filter.roleFilter.map(x => x.value);`?

Comment: const role = this.filter.roleFilter;  because the filter was indeed an array of strings